# Optimizing PostGIS view including counts with attribute join

Tags: postgis, sql-view

I try to create a PostGIS view in which I want the number of features having an attribute date < 3 years from current date, and the total number of features, to be able to display a pie chart in QGIS.
The features needs to be grouped by town (commune in French) and sometimes by a smaller town division called "tournee" in this case.

I have a materialized view which contains the towns and tournees, with the geometry.

The features I need to count are in two different tables.

My first try is working but is not efficient when I display the view in QGIS.

The view is created with the following SQL :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW deci.v_pei_avancee_rop_communes_tournees
AS
 -- Get feature from the two soruce table (features to count)
 WITH t1 AS (
         SELECT pei_raccorde.code_insee,
            pei_raccorde.commune,
            pei_raccorde.numero_tournee,
            pei_raccorde.date_suppression,
            pei_raccorde.date_reco_ops
           FROM deci.pei_raccorde
        UNION ALL
         SELECT pei_na_non_raccorde.code_insee,
            pei_na_non_raccorde.commune,
            pei_na_non_raccorde.numero_tournee,
            pei_na_non_raccorde.date_suppression,
            pei_na_non_raccorde.date_reco_ops
           FROM deci.pei_na_non_raccorde
  ORDER BY code_insee, numero_tournee
 )
 -- Create view attributes
 SELECT 
    -- view id
    row_number() OVER () AS id,
    -- town/subdivision name
    CASE
        -- if town does not have a subdivision
        WHEN t1.numero_tournee IS NULL
        -- name is the town name
        THEN t1.commune::text
        -- else concat town name and subdivision name
        ELSE concat(t1.commune, '-Tournée ', t1.numero_tournee)
    END AS commune_tournee,
    -- count the features when date_reco_ops is < 3 years before current year
    count(
        CASE
            WHEN (date_part('year'::text, now()) - date_part('year'::text, t1.date_reco_ops)) < 3::double precision THEN 1
            ELSE NULL::integer
        END) AS nb_controles
    -- count all features
    count(*) AS nb_pei,
    -- geometry : get from materialized view ct
    ct.geom
   FROM t1
     -- join with materialized view v_communes_tournees on fields code_insee and numero_tournee
     JOIN deci.v_communes_tournees ct ON ct.code_insee::text = t1.code_insee::text AND NOT ct.numero_tournee::text IS DISTINCT FROM t1.numero_tournee::text
  -- get only features where date_suppression is not filled (=null)
  WHERE t1.date_suppression IS NULL
  GROUP BY t1.code_insee, t1.commune, t1.numero_tournee, ct.geom
  ORDER BY t1.code_insee, t1.numero_tournee;
```

I have the following indexes :

- geom (gist) on the materialized view
- code_insee and numero_tournee (btree) on the materialized view and the 2 source tables

In QGIS the materialized view is **fast** to display.
The deci.v_pei_avancee_rop_communes_tournees view is slow to display (even withou the pie chart).

Add JSON QUERY PLAN :

```
  [
  {
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "WindowAgg",
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Actual Rows": 389,
      "Actual Loops": 1,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "Aggregate",
          "Strategy": "Sorted",
          "Partial Mode": "Simple",
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Actual Rows": 389,
          "Actual Loops": 1,
          "Group Key": [
            "pei_raccorde.code_insee",
            "pei_raccorde.numero_tournee",
            "pei_raccorde.commune",
            "ct.geom"
          ],
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Node Type": "Incremental Sort",
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Actual Rows": 9610,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Sort Key": [
                "pei_raccorde.code_insee",
                "pei_raccorde.numero_tournee",
                "pei_raccorde.commune",
                "ct.geom"
              ],
              "Presorted Key": [
                "pei_raccorde.code_insee"
              ],
              "Full-sort Groups": {
                "Group Count": 109,
                "Sort Methods Used": [
                  "quicksort"
                ],
                "Sort Space Memory": {
                  "Average Sort Space Used": 517,
                  "Peak Sort Space Used": 522
                }
              },
              "Pre-sorted Groups": {
                "Group Count": 111,
                "Sort Methods Used": [
                  "quicksort"
                ],
                "Sort Space Memory": {
                  "Average Sort Space Used": 1375,
                  "Peak Sort Space Used": 1560
                }
              },
              "Plans": [
                {
                  "Node Type": "Merge Join",
                  "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                  "Parallel Aware": false,
                  "Join Type": "Inner",
                  "Actual Rows": 9610,
                  "Actual Loops": 1,
                  "Inner Unique": false,
                  "Merge Cond": "((ct.code_insee)::text = (pei_raccorde.code_insee)::text)",
                  "Join Filter": "(NOT ((ct.numero_tournee)::text IS DISTINCT FROM (pei_raccorde.numero_tournee)::text))",
                  "Rows Removed by Join Filter": 34024,
                  "Plans": [
                    {
                      "Node Type": "Sort",
                      "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                      "Parallel Aware": false,
                      "Actual Rows": 426,
                      "Actual Loops": 1,
                      "Sort Key": [
                        "ct.code_insee"
                      ],
                      "Sort Method": "quicksort",
                      "Sort Space Used": 2132,
                      "Sort Space Type": "Memory",
                      "Plans": [
                        {
                          "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
                          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                          "Parallel Aware": false,
                          "Relation Name": "v_communes_tournees",
                          "Alias": "ct",
                          "Actual Rows": 426,
                          "Actual Loops": 1
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "Node Type": "Materialize",
                      "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
                      "Parallel Aware": false,
                      "Actual Rows": 43635,
                      "Actual Loops": 1,
                      "Plans": [
                        {
                          "Node Type": "Sort",
                          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                          "Parallel Aware": false,
                          "Actual Rows": 9611,
                          "Actual Loops": 1,
                          "Sort Key": [
                            "pei_raccorde.code_insee",
                            "pei_raccorde.numero_tournee"
                          ],
                          "Sort Method": "quicksort",
                          "Sort Space Used": 1099,
                          "Sort Space Type": "Memory",
                          "Plans": [
                            {
                              "Node Type": "Append",
                              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                              "Parallel Aware": false,
                              "Actual Rows": 9625,
                              "Actual Loops": 1,
                              "Subplans Removed": 0,
                              "Plans": [
                                {
                                  "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
                                  "Parent Relationship": "Member",
                                  "Parallel Aware": false,
                                  "Relation Name": "pei_raccorde",
                                  "Alias": "pei_raccorde",
                                  "Actual Rows": 9569,
                                  "Actual Loops": 1,
                                  "Filter": "(date_suppression IS NULL)",
                                  "Rows Removed by Filter": 78
                                },
                                {
                                  "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
                                  "Parent Relationship": "Member",
                                  "Parallel Aware": false,
                                  "Relation Name": "pei_na_non_raccorde",
                                  "Alias": "pei_na_non_raccorde",
                                  "Actual Rows": 56,
                                  "Actual Loops": 1,
                                  "Filter": "(date_suppression IS NULL)",
                                  "Rows Removed by Filter": 0
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "Triggers": []
  }
]
```

Comment: please add the output of `explain analyze` on your query

Comment: If the materialized view is slow, there is no way to make a view on it be much faster... so focus on making the MV fast(er) first. See this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408600/qgis-slow-performance-with-postgresql-postgis/408602#408602)

Comment: On a side note, `row_number() OVER () AS id` is wrong. You must include an `order by` within the `over` clause, else there is no guarantee that the same row will have the same ID in subsequent calls (like between fetching the shape and the attributes)

Comment: @JGH : sorry, I typed slow to display for the materialized view but it is fast ! I edited the post.

Comment: @IanTurton I added the JSON Query plan, is it ok for you ? I don't know how to get the output of explain analyse other way.

Comment: The casting of the dates to text (in your count() expression) seems wrong. Also, maybe it gets faster when you move the year difference calculation out to the CTE and only do the counting in the view? It should not matter, but it may...

Answer (score 1):

I finally rebuild my query from scratch.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW deci.v_pei_avancee_rop_communes_tournees
 AS
-- CTE t1 : get all features to count
with t1 as
    (select code_insee, commune, numero_tournee, date_suppression, date_reco_ops from deci.pei_raccorde
    union all
    select code_insee, commune, numero_tournee, date_suppression, date_reco_ops from deci.pei_na_non_raccorde),
-- CTE t2 : count the features when date_reco_ops is < 3 years before current year + count the total number of features, grouped by town and sudvision when there are ones
t2 as 
    (select code_insee,
            commune,
            numero_tournee,
            -- count according to date
            count((CASE
            WHEN (date_part('year', now()) - date_part('year', date_reco_ops)) < 3 THEN 1
                ELSE NULL
            END)) AS nb_controles,
            -- total feature count
            count(*) as nb_pei
    from t1
    -- filters for features to ignore
     where date_suppression is null and code_insee <> 'tempo'
    -- group
    group by code_insee, commune, numero_tournee
    order by code_insee, numero_tournee)
-- build view with id, town id/subdivision/town name
-- + get geom from other table (was a materialized view in my previous post but I changed it to a table)
select  row_number() over() as id,
        ct.code_insee,
        ct.commune,
        ct.numero_tournee, 
        -- default value 0 when a town has no features joined
        coalesce(t2.nb_controles, 0) as nb_controles,
        -- default value 0 when a town has no features joined
        coalesce(t2.nb_pei, 0) as nb_pei,
        nb_pei-nb_controles as nb_a_controler,
        -- geometry get from table communes_tournees
        ct.geom
from deci.communes_tournees ct
-- left join because I want to keep towns with no features
left join t2
-- join on code_insee et numero_tournee which have a composite index in all 3 tables : communes_tournees, pei_raccorde and pei_na_non_raccorde
on (ct.code_insee = t2.code_insee
and NOT ct.numero_tournee IS DISTINCT FROM t2.numero_tournee);
```

And I created composite indexes, for example as following :

```
CREATE INDEX idx_pei_raccorde_insee_tournee
    ON deci.pei_raccorde USING btree
    (code_insee, numero_tournee)
;
```

The display in QGIS is fast and I've been able to create my symbology now.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to refactor; run something like this:

```
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
    ORDER BY code_insee, commune, numero_tournee
  ) AS id,
  COALESCE(commune || '-Tournée ' || numero_tournee, commune) AS commune_tournee
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      code_insee,
      commune,
      numero_tournee,
      COUNT(*) FILTER(
        WHERE date_reco_ops >= NOW() - INTERVAL '3 YEARS'
      ) AS nb_controles,
      COUNT(*) AS nb_pei
    FROM
      (
        SELECT * FROM
          deci.pei_raccorde
        WHERE
          date_suppression IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM
          deci.pei_na_non_raccorde
        WHERE
          date_suppression IS NULL
      ) q
    GROUP BY
      1, 2, 3
  ) AS mv
JOIN
  deci.v_communes_tournees AS gv
    ON
      mv.code_insee = gv.code_insee
    AND
      mv.numero_tournee = gv.numero_tournee
;
```

**Notes:**

- it feels like those two feature tables should undergo normalization

  - merge into one with an attribute denoting the actual difference
  - have a composite key for `code_insee, numero_tournee`
- to boost the `JOIN` to your `MATERIALIZED VIEW`, you want to either

  - have a composite `INDEX` on `(code_insee, numero_tournee)`
  - use a related composite key (as above) between both tables
- `AND NOT ... IS DISTINCT FROM ...` *is not distinct from* `=` and does not trigger an index lookup
- if there is an index on `date_reco_ops`, you need to trigger it correctly; extracting parts of it will deny the index
- having `NULL`s as `JOIN` condition (as with your `numero_tournee` column) is an anti-pattern: consider to add an actual value instead

Comment: thanks for your precise answer.
- Regarding the two tables, I have no possibility to change them, it is like this on purpose :(
- I did create composite indexes (see my own answer to this post)
- Regarding the date, I don't need the whole date to be less than 3 years but the plain year. So the interval you propose is not ok for my need
- I used is distinct from to be able to join wether the numero_tournee is null or filled. It seems to work, whereas = is not working. So I'm surprised with your remark
- regarding nulls in numero_tournee, which actual value do you mean ?

Comment: That is exactly the issue, and actually I should have noted that when stating to use `=`: `NULL`s *are no values*, they describe the *absence* of values, and thus won't get indexed and are not comparable and have all sorts of no good consequences when present in dimension columns. You are depending on that column as dimension column in a multitude of ways, and thus you really should come up with an actual *null* ***value*** (e.g. `0`, `<null>`, `-1.0`, something you won't use otherwise) rather than using `NULL`!

Comment: I'm not sure to understand everything you wrote. English is not my native language and I'm surely missing some DB concepts you have. 

I will see what is possible in the future but I can't modify the tables design right now. 

I understand null represent the absence of value but I'm still surprised you wrote that `NOT ... IS DISTINCT FROM` is the equivalent of `=` because I don't get the same result when using one or the other.