# PostgreSQL 'UNION ALL' statement in a view does not load in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql, sql-view

I have two datasets, sharing the same attributes (but being distinct from each other), each in their PostGIS table. The tables are huge (both geometrical and containing ~1 billion features) and have geometrical indexes. I followed the tutorial on: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/union-all-data-types-performance/ on how to properly achieve a union of two tables:

- The tables must use the same sequence for the primary key (in this case `id`)
- The tables must have the same data types for each attribute (including the geometries)

The most simple version of the view is:

```sql
CREATE VIEW combined AS (
 SELECT table_1.id, table_1.geom FROM table_1
UNION ALL
 SELECT table_2.id, table_2.geom FROM table_2
);
```

This works like a charm using vanilla SQL queries on the view. Also loading into QGIS using the Data Source Manager works fine after removing the `Check PK unity`. Loading the view from the QGIS Browser does not work: on the backend I can find using `pg_stat_activity` that QGIS tries to execute the query: `SELECT count(distinct ("id"))=count(("id")) FROM "public"."combined"`, a query that gets stuck forever. I get where this is coming from, as this is the PK Unity check, but I'm wondering why that takes so long, as the IDs from both tables come from the same sequence.

I have already tried to use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` in the view, but that does not work. Is there any trick to combining two huge spatial tables that can still be loaded into QGIS using the browser?

Comment: relevant: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408600/qgis-slow-performance-with-postgresql-postgis/408602#408602

Comment: Compiling a list of 2 billion discrete values from disk is going to take a *while* in PostgreSQL, even with partitions across dozens of discrete disk devices and 16+ CPUs.

Comment: As an aside: you need to explicitly cast to the *typemod* qualified `GEOMETRY` type in order to register the geometry column of the *View* in the system tables.

Comment: You need to create a [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html), in order to create an index for the id field and speed up that check query. The overall performance will increase significantly too, but its not updated in real time as the view and need to be refreshed from time to time.