# Saving a QGIS project takes 10 minutes

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, windows, save

I run a project with about 30 layers. Some of them contains ~1.000.000 objects stored in a PostGIS/PostgreSQL database

Opening my project is fine. It takes only a few seconds

But when I save the project (without having changing anything but layer display/hide or the position) it takes about 10 minutes to save the project

Where can this come from?

Comment: Are you using OpenCL Acceleration? `Settings - > Options -> Acceleration`?

Comment: No, no acceleration yet. Will try

Comment: No change indeed....

Comment: In the connections settings of the postgis connection, try ticking "Use estimated table metadata". It has helped me opening projects faster. Dont know about saving

Comment: Indeed, the table metadata is computed on every project open and save. Maybe it has changed, but with previous versions you had to update the project file by hand ([see here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408600/qgis-slow-performance-with-postgresql-postgis/408602#408602))

Comment: You can try to enable query logging on your Postgres instance and see which command is being executed

Comment: ... and of course, start by saving your project into a new one (`save as ...`) to remove all now unused information from previous versions.

Comment: Thanks ! Log querying gave me the cause : QGIS does a "select st_extent" or "st_estimatedextent" on every layer (sometimes with a where clause on upper(geometrytype("geom"))) and it takes a lot of time. But why does it this and how to avoid it ?

Comment: @plc see the link I gave you earlier, it has details for the estimated extent and the geometry type.

Comment: Your the best. Adding estimatedmetadata=true solved my issue. Many many many many thanks !

Answer (score 2):

@JGH solved my issue. When saving the project, QGIS was recalculating all `st_extent` for all layers (around 100.000.000 lines each). By adding `estimatedmetadata=true` to `<datasource>dbname=` entries in the QGIS project file definitively solved my issue (saving takes less than 1 second now).

Answer (score 1):

What is the project CRS? What is the CRS of each layer? If you have any layers with abnormal extents, that might cause QGIS to slow down while working with them. Check the extents by selecting all your layers and running this in the Python console:

```
for layer in iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers():
    print(layer.extent())
```

If you spot any extents that are *way* outside the project CRS, that might be your problem...

Comment: HI
All layers are in EPSG:4326 - WGS 84
All extents seems OK
I have no issue opening the project (a few seconds), neither when hiding/unhiding layers or scrolling or getting information abour an object.
My only issue is when sabing the project wich takes bout 7 to 10 minutes to complete